# multiplying textbox values

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Problem: I have 3 text boxes:subtotal, tax, and total. I want the value in the subtotal text box to be multiplied by the value in the tax textbox and be displayed in the total text feild.

I have created a JS Fiddle!
You can see the subtotal working perfectly on my site!

Js fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/eeMva/

My site http://soldbybillcox.com/treasure/demo.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/eeMva/ ?? **or** http://jsfiddle.net/eeMva/1/ with multiplication of subtotal and tax

plz note

- your keyup event is changed.
- jsfiddle had mootool in it not jquery.
- removed few comments

Hope this helps the cause `:)`
**code**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    calculateSum();
    $(".txt").keyup(function() {
    $(".txt").each(function() {

            calculateSum();
        });
    });
});


$("#tax").keyup(function() {

    $('#total1').val(parseInt($(this).val()) * parseInt($('#subtotal').val()));

});

function calculateSum() {
    var sum = 0;
    $("#sum").val(sum.toFixed(2));
    //iterate through each textboxes and add the values
    $(".txt").each(function() {
        //add only if the value is number
        if (!isNaN(this.value) && this.value.length != 0) {
            sum += parseFloat(this.value);
        }
    });
    $("#sum").html(sum.toFixed(2));
    var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal").value == "";
    var subtotal = document.getElementById("subtotal").value = sum;


    function getTax(tax) {
        var taxFloat = parseFloat(tax)
        if (isNaN(taxFloat)) {
            return 1;
        } else {
            return taxFloat;
        }
    }

    var total = getTax($('#tax').val()) * sum;
    var total1 = document.getElementById("total1").value = total;

}
```

Comment: @tman yo sup man, howz it going? `:)` bit busy :P should I take a look in a bit lol and have you copy pasted the whole code,

Comment: @tman +1 to your question & comment anyways lol - add this on top of you page: `<script type='text/javascript' src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js'></script>` I reckon your JQuery library is not sourcing into your page, cheers

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you haven't selected jQuery as the framework on the left in your JS Fiddle, and also that you are using HTML comments inside of Javascript, for example:

```
<!-- TAXES -->
```

When writing Javascript you should use JS comments, for example:

```
/*
 * Taxes, or
 */
// Single line comment
```

Comment: yea i got that worked out but this is not the cause of my mutiplication not working any clue how to fix this i changed the link to the js fiddle